# Error using ncdump - NetCDF4 Python

Tags: python

I am using python to read a netcdf dataset. I have installed netcdf and I am trying to read the data by typing, 
ncdump("sample.nc",header_only=0). And I get the below error:
/bin/sh: 1: ncdump.exe: not found.

sample.nc is a netcdf file created using the following code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset    
import numpy as np

sfile = Dataset('sample.nc',mode='w', format='NETCDF4')
```

Can anyone help me understand this error. I am quite new to this concept.
Thanks

Comment: Which `ncdump` do you use? Please provide full code snippet.

Comment: You are opening a netcdf file for writing when you use `mode='w'`.  If you are trying to read a dataset, there are many example using python.  Here is one: https://wakari.io/sharing/bundle/rsignell/cf_3d_to_1d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem today, and I came across your question during my research to solve my problem.  You don't have the ncdump command installed most likely.

Download netCDF4.3.3.1-NC4-64.exe or the 32 bit version from the http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/winbin.html.

I installed them to my program files.  Add the path to the ncdump commands to your system path.  I believe they are located in the bin folder once you have run the install.  My path was...

C:\Program Files (x86)\netCDF 4.3.3.1\bin

Good Luck.

```
ncdump -h filename
```

in command prompt should work